# How to store the last variable in a list

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code with which I get the last value in a list:

```
 Range("B3").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.End(xlDown).Select
```

Only thing is that I would like to store that selection as a value. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

If I do this:

```
 Range("B3").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Var = Selection.End(xlDown).Select
```

Var just prints TRUE

Comment: you want to store the value of the last cell ? or it's address ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better if you avoid using `Select` and `Selection`, instead use  qualified objects, like `Worksheet` and `Range`.

**Note**: Using `.End(xlDown)` to get the last row only works if your data has no gaps (empty rows).

In case you do have empty rows, and you want to get the last cell, then use the following line instead:

```
.Range("B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
```

### Code

```
Sub LastCellVariable()

Dim Var

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' to get the value from the last cell
    Var = .Range("B3").End(xlDown).Value

    ' to get the cell's address from the last cell
    Var = .Range("B3").End(xlDown).Address
End With

End Sub
```